# Can not communicate between subnets in the same virtual network

Tags: azure-virtual-machine, azure-virtual-network

Not sure what is exactly happening since it was always working before but VMs on different subnets within the same virtual network with no NSGs or firewalls between them can not talk to each other. Ping is failing as well as any other sort of communication. Firewalls are disabled on both sides. All machines have access to internet. Communication was tried using IP addresses and not names. Both ping as well as TCP based tests were used.

[image]

Effective route for app01 for example is below
[image]

Comment: Are the Vms are in the Same affinity group?

Comment: Those are ARM deployment, so there are no affinity groups

Comment: Try adding another default route with an address prefix of 10.0.1.0/24 and Hop Type as Virtual Network

Comment: Which subnet it shall be associated with

Comment: Add manual route for 10.0.1.0/24 and 10.0.0.0/24 to both subnet with Next Hop Type virtual network, issue still persists

Comment: By default, VM in a same VNet could not communicate. Do you associate NSG to subnet(not VM)?

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/iaDlB This is null?

Comment: Yes, there is no security groups. I would assume having no security groups means there is nothing restricts traffic and hence all traffic shall be allowed. My understanding by default all VMs on the same VNET shall be able to communicate with each other and traffic between them automatically routed.

Comment: I associated NSGs to both subnets to test and it still did not fix the issue. Per https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/network-overview VMs shall be able automatically communicate with each other on the same VNET with no additional setup

Comment: @GregorySuvalian For test, not ping the private IP, could your RDP the VM's private IP? By default, the port 3398 is open on Windows Firewall and Azure NSG.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/163837/discussion-between-shengbao-shui-msft-and-gregory-suvalian).

Comment: Was the issue resolved with your support request? I just got the exact same issue. Azure support keeps claiming that my service doesn't listen to IPv4. There's a docker-compose service running in the brackground and netstat output display listeing on IPv6. But IPv4 forwarding is configured. When I call the service from a different machine within the same subnet, using an IPv4 address, the response is confirmed with a status 200 code. For testing I created a new VM within a third subnet and the request failed. Curiously, the IP can be resolved via nslookup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, Azure allows communicate between subnets in a same VNet.

Your issue seems a issue on Azure side, I suggest you could [open a ticket on Azure Portal](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-supportability/how-to-create-azure-support-request).